# iOS Crash inside Location framework

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I have couple review from users, like App crash right now after start.

```
-[CLLocationManager onClientEventAuthStatus:]
```

I check logs from Apple and find something interesting.

[image]

Looks like I have crash inside Location framework.

What I'm doing in code:

```
class MyAppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

 lazy var locationManager = {
        return CLLocationManager()
 }()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        ...

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        return true
     }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        //save location to property
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Also I set property `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` with some text.

I checked All scenario like Location was disabled. And I can't reproduce any crash. Do you have any idea what can be reason?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see the pop up window that asks for the users location? I have had an issue before where I tried getting a users location from a class that was not a view controller and because I was not in a view controller the alert view that asks for the users location was not being displayed, thus restricting me from obtaining the users location.

Comment: Yes, I can see request for access. But maybe you right. But I can't reproduce it.